# What component is this? (photo)

Tags: surface-mount, damage

My PC powered off out of the blue one night and when I opened it to look for a burning smell I didn't notice any, so I thought it might be due to a power surge and tried to boot up the PC again with the cabinet open and that is when I saw a yellow spark fly out from the graphic card. I checked my PowerColor HD 7970 graphic card and I noticed a burnt out component on the back side.

I've marked the burnt out component in the cropped photo below.
[image: C610 - Back side of PowerColor 7970]

Initially I thought it was a Surface Mount Capacitor because of the 'C' in the label C610. So tried to contact a computer repairs shop and they said that it wasn't a capacitor but I'm not sure if the guy knew what it actually was.
**Can someone help me figure out what type of a component it is?** I'm assuming C610 is the same as C618 or C623 because it looks like they are the same size.

P.S. My PC boots up fine using the on board graphic card it has so there is not damage to the motherboard I think.

Also I have a multi-meter available in case you want me to test something and report back.

Update : The IC 8510 301-24 U1216 below the burnt capacitor in the photo is dead too.

Comment: It's definitely a capacitor. Ask the manufacturer what value it (and C626, since it's possible that it was damaged as well) has.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio, I was thinking about that too.. I just wrote them an email.. Let me see if they reply..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, according to the picture it looks like you have 5 examples of the circuit side by side from left to right - they all interface with identical chips (U1216 written on them amongst other similar identifiers). I've marked each circuit with a white box: -

[image]

So, get someone to remove one of the components that should be identical and get them to measure it to confirm it is a capacitor and buy a replacement.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and mentioning the similar connections you noticed on the 2nd pin from top-left on U1216 :)
I'll try finding someone to identify that part and replace it.

Btw, I would be wrong in assuming that C610 (burnt) and C618 would be same just based on the size right?

Comment: Btw, would it be possible that the surrounding parts, specially the tiny one on the left got damaged by the heat from the burnt out capacitor?

Comment: C626 could be damaged so it's probably a good idea to change it. If you dare apply power you could measure the voltage on C615 (what looks like a good circuit) and see if it is a recognizable power rail voltage and then that gives a decent clue as to the cap voltage rating. If it is 5V then skip a 6V3 rating and look for at least a 10V rating. I would assume C610 is more likely comparable with C615.

Comment: Not having a good luck finding any details about U1216. I'll try powering on and testing the cap voltage as a last resort.

Comment: You don't need to - I was just pointing out that part as being the "heart" of a small circuit that is repeated across the picture.

Comment: I just found out that the IC 8510 301-24 U1216 below the burnt capacitor is dead too... We tried to find that IC locally and on google but no luck. Anyone knows a source for buying it?

Comment: I searched at the time but found nothing. On one of the working circuits maybe you can extract waveforms and raise a question about what type of chip it could be.

Comment: Thanks, I gave up on finding the IC. We removed the damaged cap and didn't replace it yet.. I plugged the card in, booted the PC up and the card works.. I'm going to try and check again why the guy though the IC 851 301-24 U1216 was damaged too and maybe give replacing the capacitor a thought..

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why the guy in the computer repair shop would claim it's something other than a capacitor - it is *obviously* a capacitor, for three reasons:

1. It's named Cxxx
2. It's placed in parallel with a lot of other capacitors
3. The placement indicates that it belongs to the power supply section

As for the value and voltage rating, that's more difficult. There are minor differences between each section. With any luck you will find a recommended value from the datasheet of the controller IC. It's unlikely to be critical.

In fact, it would not surprise me if the graphics card still works if you clean the soot off.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance. I thought the same that if I did try using the card up again it MIGHT run, but I didn't want to risk it.

Going to try finding recommended value based on the IC.